# Create image from remote URL and add it to a cell

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion. I am creating a custom tableview row
and I want to add a big image to it from a remote API (get the URL from the JSON object).

How can I do this? I cannot find anywhere how to create an image from a remote URL and then add it to the cell.

Thankful for all help!

**Update**

I am using this code now but the performance is very bad when scrolling the table.

```
url = NSURL.URLWithString("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1d92e61d7066383b1e3c797ea635f86e?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG")
    data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url)
    remote = UIImage.imageWithData(data)
    image = UIImageView.alloc.initWithFrame([[50, 50],[150, 50]])
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
    image.image = remote
```

**Update 2**

I ended up with this code that go good performance. Now I just need to figure our how to cache the images.

```
Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
      data = NSData.alloc.initWithContentsOfURL(NSURL.URLWithString(post.image_medium))
      if data
        image = UIImage.alloc.initWithData(data)
        Dispatch::Queue.main.sync do
          image_view = UIImageView.alloc.initWithFrame([[210, 10],[80, 80]])
          image_view.image = image
          view.addSubview(image_view)
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one image in one cell use

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/exampleImage.png"]];
yourCell.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

If you have lots of then or don't want to block the UI use [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

Comment: Thanks! But how can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: Sorry, I read it fast and didn't notice you are using rubymotion. I though you where using ruby on the server. I don't know the rubymotion syntax, but the first part should be similar to the code I posted. I looked at the rubymotion doc and you have the NSURL, NSData UIImage and UITableViewCell. The steps are the same.

Comment: I tried and I succeeded to convert your code to Ruby (see updated) but the performance is very poor when I scroll.

Comment: That's why I recommended AsyncImageView, but I don't think you can use it with rubymotion

Comment: I have updated my question with a code that gives good performance.